# c# cannot go to definition / implementation /reference with VSCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am using c# with vscode. My system is Ubuntu 20.04, the VSCode version is 1.58. I have installed the C#, C# extensions, and dotnet, but I still cannot use any C# language services (like go to definition) shown in the picture below. I have also tried to install python and C/C++, and the language services are working well for the python and C code. So I am confused why I cannot use the language service for C#. Do I need to install any extra package to use the C# services, or is there any solution to enable the C# language service? Thanks in advance for any suggestion:))
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved. I just pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, then *Select Project*, and finally changed from `.sln` to `.csproj`. At least, this worked for me.